# Calling python from LibreOffice Calc 'in cell' formula

Tags: python, formula, libreoffice, calc

In LibreOffice Calc, I want to have a cell, e.g. cell A1, contain a formula like "=RunMyPythonScript(B1, C1, D1)" which reads cells B1, C1, D1, and then cell A1 displays the return result from an embedded python macro:

```
def RunMyPythonScript (cell1, cell2, cell2):
    return cell1+cell2+cell3
```

I came across an old article
https://superuser.com/questions/1297120/use-a-python-function-as-formula-in-libreoffice-calc-cells
in which Jim K tried to give a solution which verbatum says

```
g_exportedScripts = call_vol,
```

including the comma, which looks like an error and doesn't work (even without the comma). To be able to do this would be super useful. Can anyone resolve this (in a 'modern' e.g. approx, python 3.8+ and LibreOffice 7.3+ context) and/or suggest the correction/explanation as the the suspected erroneous line> by Jim K.

## ---------------------

Hi Jim. Thanks for your help.
I got it working by slightly different means, but would still love to get your method working and fully understand it.

For the benefit of others I did this...

In LO cell A1 I have:

```
=BAS_RUNMYPYHTONSCRIPT(B1,C1,D1)
```

which calls a BASIC script.

The BASIC script is as follows:

```
Function bas_runmypythonscript(arg1, arg2, arg3)  ' define a BASIC function_
                                   ' that replicates the python function.    
    Dim py_fn_file as Object
    
    py_fn_file = ThisComponent.getScriptProvider().getScript( _
    "vnd.sun.star.script:py_script_test.py$RunMyPythonScript?language=Python&location=user")
    
    bas_runmypythonscript = py_fn_file.invoke(Array(arg1, arg2, arg3), Array(), Array() )
```

And in my /home/LINUX_USER/.config/libreoffice/4/user/Scripts/python
folder I have a file called py_script_test.py
which contains the simple python code:

````
def RunMyPythonScript (cell1, cell2, cell2):
    return cell1+cell2+cell3```
````

Comment: The trailing comma creates a tuple. If you don't like how it looks, then add parentheses: `g_exportedScripts = (call_vol,)`. As to why it's not working, did you write the necessary Basic UDF to call it, as explained in the link from that answer? Or implement the function as a spreadsheet add-in, which is better because it does not require Basic glue code, although the required XML declaration files are more difficult to write.

Comment: Thanks Jim K!.
Sadly the comments section isn't capable of hosting my reply to your helpful and appreciated comment, so I edited my original post. The 'alternative' method came from this YouTube video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=841Fgt1sQsY&t=2084s by D Tim Cummings (tq).
I am really curious about this 'spreadsheet add-in' - could you elaborate on it?

Comment: Here is an updated link to the add-ins help page: https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/scalc/01/04060112.html. For a python example, the extension at https://extensions.libreoffice.org/en/extensions/show/lingtools includes a calc add-in called `REVERSE()` that reverses a string. It works in recent versions of LO.